# Who is charged when a user download data from an external bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Who is charged when a user downloads data from an external bucket ? The owner of the bucket, the account who's downloading the data, or both ?

Edit: By external bucket I mean a bucket that doesn't belong to the account used to download the data. For instance, company A wants to share data from its own bucket X, and company B wants to download the data from X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "external bucket", but in any case the bucket owner is charged for bandwidth resulting from object downloads (listed as "Egress" on the [GCS pricing page](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricing-and-terms)).

Comment: I'm updating the question to explain what I mean by external bucket.

Comment: Is it always true ? The owner always has to pay, or is there any way to share the cost ?

Comment: It is always true. The project owning the bucket is responsible for 100% of the fee.

Comment: And if you think about it, how would you even charge the downloading user? Usually all the server sees is an IP address.

Comment: It's not totally accurate. Google Storage supports authentication and fine-grained permissions. The server knows exactly which Google Account is accessing the data.

Comment: Anyway, I'm accepting your answer since it's confirmed by a Google developer. Thanks all.

Comment: Keep in mind that objects can be made fully public, i.e., anyone can download them (without authorization) -- what you're suggesting would not work there. (P.S. I'm a Google dev, too ;))